# RichFaces / Ajax4JSF: How to turn off JavaScript obfuscation?

Tags: javascript, richfaces, obfuscation, ajax4jsf

How can I turn off JavaScript shortening in A4J? I remember there was an option, possibly used during build, which made `.js` files not being processed by some shortner / obfuscator, thus remaining nicely formatted. But I can't remember what it was or find it on the web.

Anyone knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like the param is

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See http://community.jboss.org/message/32022#32022

Comment: Ah, damn, I copied the wrong section of a XML snippet from a wrong  page :)  Thanks for correction.